# Shopify clear drawer cart before add to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am using Brooklyn theme and drawer cart and want to clear my cart before adding particular product. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. How can i make a post request to clear my cart?

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.clear-cart').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/cart/clear.js',
      success: function(){
        alert('You cleared the cart!');
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue with this JS code, you need to provide more info like console error or behavior of cart after using the same code, or website link is the best to check.

Comment: @Onkar there is no error in console, Just nothing happens. Is the js right or its impossible to say wirhout another code?

Comment: you need to post the URL to check it on the website.